# Hiding TabBarController titles

Tags: ios

You can customize the tabbarcontroller with your own images but you have to add a title that goes underneath the image. If I just want to have the image with no title, I just put nothing for the title, however there is an empty space below the image. How do I remove the empty space below the image?